# Get data from Json API

Tags: json, swift

I want to get the JSON data from the urlString but I don't know what value to put in the `jsonObj!.value(forKey: "") as?`. If you look at the JSON structure it doesn't have a main name to get into the data.

```
final let urlString = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" 

func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: ""))

            if let actorArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "") as? NSArray {
                for actor in actorArray{
                    if let actorDict = actor as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = actorDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                            self.nameArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = actorDict.value(forKey: "rank") {
                            self.rankArray.append(name as! String)
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

The JSON structure

```
[
    {
    id: "bitcoin",
    name: "Bitcoin",
    symbol: "BTC",
    rank: "1",
    price_usd: "9361.68",
    price_btc: "1.0",
    24h_volume_usd: "9720310000.0",
    market_cap_usd: "156442678736",
    available_supply: "16710962.0",
    total_supply: "16710962.0",
    max_supply: "21000000.0",
    percent_change_1h: "-1.11",
    percent_change_24h: "-15.97",
    percent_change_7d: "14.51",
    last_updated: "1512057553"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: It's an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: ... and `NSURL`, `valueForKey` and `.allowFragments`. And the code will crash reliably if an error occurs in `dataTask(with` or `jsonObject(with`

Comment: Did you write this code yourself or did you copy a lot of it from somewhere else? I ask because it has many, many issues. If you copied it from somewhere else, find a better tutorial.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy. I would also recommend using Swiftyjson to parse the JSON and Alamofire to make the request opposed to the code above.

Comment: @NevinJethmalani Alamofire is overkill for a simple GET request and SwiftyJSON doesn't help if you have no idea how to read the JSON and it's going to become obsolete in Swift 4 due to `Codable`.

Comment: as? [[String:String]] or [[String:Any]]